# How to retrieve each parent group of an Active Directory group

Tags: c++, active-directory

I have an Active Directory set up with a number of groups, levels of sub-groups, and then users within those sub groups.

I want to specify a group name and retrieve all groups that the group belongs to (either immediately or further up the hierarchy, not important which).

I have code which finds groups that a user belongs to and iterates through them to see if they match with a specified group name, but I can't figure out how to specify a group and search for those groups.

```
IADsUser *user_object = NULL;
IADsMembers *members;

// ...
// Get object via ADsGetObject
// ...

// Provides me with a list of groups that the user belongs to
user_object->Groups(&members);
```

The IADsGroup class does not contain a Groups() function so I cannot see how I can retrieve a list of groups that a group belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the [`memberOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-memberof) attribute of the group, using [`IADs::GetEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-iads-getex).

If you have an `IADsGroup group_object`:

```cpp
HRESULT hr;
VARIANT groups;
VariantInit(&groups);
hr = group_object->GetEx(CComBSTR("memberOf"), &groups);
```

The `groups` variable will now be a `VARIANT` array containing the `distinguishedName` of all the groups. If you want to get the friendly name of each one, then you'll need to bind to each group (using `ADsGetObject`) to get an `IADsGroup` object for that group.

The `memberOf` attribute does have some caveats that you should be aware of, which I wrote about [here](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/07/what-makes-a-member.html#beware-of-memberof), but if you're on a single-domain environment with no external, trusted domains, then it shouldn't matter to you.

Note that the return value `hr` might be `E_ADS_PROPERTY_NOT_FOUND` if it is not a member of any other groups. Active Directory in general treats empty attributes as non-existent.

Comment: Thanks. Currently I am trying to retrieve the group object in the following way:


`hr = ADsGetObject(CT2CW(name_path), IID_IADsGroup, (void **)&group_object);`

Where `name_path` is "LDAP://CN=GroupName", but group_object comes back null.

I guess it's the LDAP path that is wrong but I'm not sure what should go there and I haven't got access to the machine running the Active Directory.

Comment: Ignore that please, I've got the LDAP path right and the group_object is successfull populated. Now however the GetEx call for "memberOf" returns an empty value, even though I know the specified group is a member of other groups.

Comment: So `groups.vt == VT_EMPTY`? The array itself should be in `groups.parray`.